# Add confidence interval with labels to a bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the following data:

```
df.plot <- data.frame(x=c("outcome name","outcome name"),
                      Condition=c("A","B"),
                      Score=c(41.5,51.8))
```

I can produce the following graph:

[image]

With this code:

```
ggplot(df.plot, aes(x=x, y=Score, fill=Condition)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity', width=.5) +
  xlab(NULL) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(Score,2)), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), vjust=-0.25)
```

I would like to add a confidence interval to the "B" bar that goes from 27.5 to 76.1. I would like those values to be labeled in the graph.

I tried modifying `df.plot` to include this information and using `geom_errorbar` but i endup with 2 intervals intead of just one for Condition "B"

```
df.plot <- data.frame(x=c("outcome name","outcome name"),
                      Condition=c("A","B"),
                      Score=c(41.5,51.8),
                      lb = c(NULL,27.5),
                      ub = c(NULL,76.1))

ggplot(df.plot, aes(x=x, y=Score, fill=Condition)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity', width=.5) +
  xlab(NULL) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lb, ymax = ub),
                width = 0.2,
                linetype = "dotted",
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
                color="red", size=1)    +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(Score,2)), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), vjust=-0.25)
```

[image]

Finally, i'm not sure how to add the labels to the top and bottom of the interval.

Comment: Aaaah, ggplot... Go with ggplot... Here is an elegant solution with just base R - using `barplot` and `segments` and `arrows` to add the CI whiskers :-) https://datascienceplus.com/building-barplots-with-error-bars/

Comment: @ignacio, can I ask how you found the confidence interval? is there a specific function to do it in R? I want to the same things you've done, but I am not sure how I can calculate a confidence interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NA` is used for missing values not `NULL`

This should work as you expect:

```
df.plot <- data.frame(x=c("outcome name","outcome name"),
                  Condition=c("A","B"),
                  Score=c(41.5,51.8),
                  lb = c(NA,27.5),
                  ub = c(NA,76.1))


ggplot(df.plot, aes(x=x, y=Score, fill=Condition)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity', width=.5) +
  xlab(NULL) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lb, ymax = ub),
            width = 0.2,
            linetype = "dotted",
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
            color="red", size=1)    +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(Score,2)), position=position_dodge(width=0.5),  vjust=-0.25) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = lb, label = lb), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), vjust=2)
```

[image: improved version]